# CSS is not working on the JavaScript code, which adds a text field on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox

I am trying to add a `text field` when user clicks the 'add' sign. The field is added, but the CSS is not working.

Here is the JavaScript I am using-

```js
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()"/>

<span id="responce"></span>
<script>
var countBox =1;
var boxName = 0;
function addInput()
{
     var boxName="textBox"+countBox; 
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br/><input type="text" id="'+boxName+'" class="search" value="'+boxName+'" "  /><br/>'
     countBox += 1;
}
</script>
```

And here is the CSS which i want to add on the `text field` that appears-

```css
.search{
            border: 1px solid #c4c4c4; 
            height: 15px; 
            font-size: 13px; 
            padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px; 
            border-radius: 4px; 
            -moz-border-radius: 4px; 
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9; 
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9; 
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9; 
        }
        .search:focus{
            outline: none; 
            border: 1px solid #7bc1f7; 
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7; 
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7; 
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7; 
        }
```

Comment: Code is perfectly working

Comment: @RoshniBokade can u tell me how can i limit the no. of textboxes?

Comment: on what basis u want to limit it or how many textboxes u want to have ??

Comment: @RoshniBokade i want to limit the no. of textbox so that a user can have only 12 textboxes

Comment: inside the function put the code- if (countBox == 13)  return false; or you can put some alert @Rajveer Singh

Comment: @RoshniBokade Thanks for answering